# SQL CHANGE DATE FORMAT IN BULK

Tags: mysql, date-format, date

I have a database with several hundred fields but my data structure is wrong. It is currently in uk format as follows:

d/m/y 01/01/85 01/01/96 23/12/87

What would be the most efficient way to change the dates in bulk to sql standard of year/month/day

eg. 02/01/85 --> 1985/01/02

Comment: Are you storing these as (var)char data types?

Comment: Doesn't he have to be? I mean, normally it's the client which imposes the diplay format.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Clean up the dates as you load the data.  How are you loading it?  `INSERT`?  `LOAD DATA INFILE`?  It is possible to do the `STR_TO_DATE()` in either case.

Plan B:  (This requires "Plan A" for future inserts.)  Devise a script, possibly mostly inside a Stored Routine that would do the following for any given column known to be a VARCHAR that should be a DATE.  (Do something similar for a DATETIME.)  Here is a *sketch* of what is needed for one $column in one $table:

1. `ALTER TABLE $table ADD COLUMN tmp DATE NOT NULL;`
2. `UPDATE $table SET tmp = STR_TO_DATE($column, '%d/%m/%Y');`
3. `ALTER TABLE $table DROP COLUMN $column, RENAME COLUMN tmp TO $column;`